# React Hooks useEffect won't use the correct state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        console.log('addedNodes', addedNodes)
        let credentials = //something...
        let nodes = [...addedNodes]
        console.log(addedNodes)
        setCurrentForm(
            {
                ...currentForm,
                credentials: credentials,
                nodes: [...addedNodes],
            }
        )
    }}
</Button>
```

I have a button that updates the `currentForm` state using another state `addedNodes`.
Whenever the `currentForm` gets updated, I console.log the `currentForm` using `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('currentForm ,,,,,, ', currentForm)
        console.log('addedNodes ,,,,,, ', addedNodes)
    }, [currentForm]);
```

This prints out the CORRECT updated state.

However, when I try to add an API request using that state, it goes back to the state before it got updated.

For example, when I update my `useEffect` to

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log('currentForm,,,,,, ', currentForm)
        console.log('addedNodes ,,,,,, ', addedNodes)
        console.log('RUNNING POST')
        setLoadingStatus('loading')

        let body = {
            form: currentForm,
        }

        intializeForms()
        let options = {
            headers: header,
            method: 'post',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        }
        console.log('options.body', options.body)

        const urls = ['...'];
        const fetchJson = url => fetch(url, options).then(res => res.json());
        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchJson))
            .then(([result]) => {
               ...
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setLoadingStatus('none')
                console.log(err)
            });

    }, [currentForm]);
```

The `console.log('options.body', options.body)` prints out the old `currentForm`.

This is very weird to be because `console.log(currentForm)` prints the expected state, but when I actually use it for an API call, it goes back to the original form.

I assume that it is because this `useEffect` gets called everytime the state gets updated, but not really sure.

Any help, please?

Comment: The `useEffect` callback is going to run every time the `currentForm` value changes, not when any other values change

Comment: @BillMetcalf what I am asking is, the `useEffect` gets the right `currentForm` but doesn't pass the right thing to the body

Comment: comment out `initializeForms()` or move into `.then`

Comment: @xadm how does `then` work in `useEffect`? Is it something like `... [currentForm]).then( ... )` ?

Comment: no ... into Promise  .then   .... but first test removing this call

Comment: @xadm Thanks. I think that was the issue!

Comment: I gues form values was objects mutated on `initializeForms` not replaced with new instances.

Comment: @xadm Yeah that makes sense.

Comment: That explains why Kaca992's solution didn't worked

Comment: So I was passing in the reference of the `currentForm` to the body and got reset before it got fed into the request body, right?

Comment: yes, but references to `currentForm` elements, I'll write explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problematic code fragment

> ```
>     let body = {
>         form: currentForm,
>     }
>     intializeForms()
>     // later bad body.form content
> ```

`form` gets a reference to `currentFrom` object then `currentFrom` is overwritten in `intializeForms()` ... this way `JSON.stringify(body)` operates on bad data.

Why Kaca992's solution didn't worked?

> ```
> let body = {
>     form: {...currentForm},
>   }
> ```

It should create a fresh object from `currentForm`' element/properties.
Probably it worked for some part of `currentForm`, f.e. for `nodes` as they was properly (in immutable way - by new instance) assigned/passed:

```
 nodes: [...addedNodes],
```

Probably other `currentForm` elements are a copies of **always the same object references**, mutated on changes, not replaced with new instances.

## Solution:

In this case it's enough to call `intializeForms()` just after `currentForm` "consuming" (stringify) - `let options =` block.

Other good place for form reset (`intializeForms()` call) can be `Promise.all(...` resolving function (`.then` part).

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What does initializeForms do? If currentForms is a reference type maybe you reset the value? Try setting the body like this:

```
    let body = {
        form: {...currentForm},
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Causing the same issue.

Comment: you also need a mechanism to bail out of the next useEffect if intializeForms changes currentForm. on the top of the useEffect some check (like if state is loading or if currentForm is null).